# How to config zipkin mysql in windows with cmd?

Tags: mysql, configuration, zipkin

What is the corresponding command for “STORAGE_TYPE=mysql MYSQL_USER=root java -jar zipkin.jar” under cmd?

I succeeded in Ubuntu, but the cmd in Windows has never been successful.

Comment: Traces Info not persisting in MYSQL

Comment: I try "java -jar zipkin.jar STORAGE_TYPE=mysql MYSQL_USER=root", but doesn't work.